# Injection in relative (co)homology

Tags: homology-cohomology

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $Y\subset X$ be a subspace. I can write the long exact sequence of relative cohomology
$$
H^{k-1}(Y)\xrightarrow{d_*} H^k(X;Y)\xrightarrow{j_*} H^k(X)\xrightarrow{i_*} H^k(Y),
$$
where the maps $i_*$ and $j_*$ are those induced in cohomology by the short exact sequence of cochain
$$ 0\rightarrow C^k(X;Y)\xrightarrow{j} C^k(X)\xrightarrow{i}C^k(Y)\rightarrow 0,$$
and the map $d_*$ is the usal map in relative cohomology.

Are there conditions equivalent to $j_*$ being injective for every $k$?

In particular, I am working with compact complex manifolds and I consider the spaces of $k$-forms as the complex of cochains.